# Joining Models in Python DRF Serializer without introducing Foreign key

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I am relatively new to Django, and DRF. I recently started a project to learn more about the platform.

I also found best practice guide line which I am following at the moment. [Here is the Django Style Guide](https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide)

The guild line says that every App should completely decouple itself and use UUID instead of foreign key,
And every business rule should go into services.py (Which I like btw.)

Here comes the problem. I am not sure how I can construct two models together to produce a nested JSON Output.

Ex: I have `Post()` model and `Comments()` model. and Comment model uses uuid of Post model as a referential id.

Now in my API.py, I am not sure how I can join these two together in the Serializer.py

***FYI the code below is only for demo purposes, may not be executable***

**Model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pictures = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    long = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    vote = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post_id =  models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    up_vote = models.IntegerField()
    down_vote = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Service**

```
def get_report(id) -> Dict:
    logger.info('Get an Report by Id')

    post= Post.objects.get(id=id)

    return {
        'post'= post
    }

def get_comments(id) -> Dict:
    logger.info('Get an Report by Id')

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=id)

    return {
        'comments' = comments 
    }
```

**API**

```
class ReportGetApi(APIView):    
     class OutputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        comments = CommentsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'pictures', 'lat', 'long', 'vote', 'comments')

    class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Comments
            fields = ('post_id', 'parent_id', 'text', 'up_vote', 'down_vote', 'user_id', 'created_at', 'modified_at')

    def get(self, request):
        post = PostService.get_post() #Only one item
        comments = PostService.get_comments() #Many Items

        serializer = self.OutputSerializer(post, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need a services file to do what you're asking. DRF can handle what you want directly with serializers and using a `RetrieveAPIView`.

So using your models you have above you *could* have something like the following:

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from . import models


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Comment
        fields = '__all__'


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_comments(self, obj):
        comments = models.Comment.objects.filter(post_id=obj.id)
        return CommentSerializer(comments, many=True).data
```

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from . import serializers, models


class ReportApi(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()
```

You would need to specify the URL to pass in the primary key of the `Post` object you want to retrieve like so:

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from api import views

app_name = 'api'
urlpatterns = [
    path('get_post_report/<pk>/', views.ReportApi.as_view()),
]
```

Then you would access the view using something like `http://example.com/api/get_post_report/12345678/`.

```
Note: You must configure the urls.py within your project's 
urls file to use 'api/' for including your app's urls for the
'/api/' part of the url above to be a part of the url.
```

If you don't know how to set up urls refer to the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/)

This will then give you something like the following:

**response.json**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "post_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
            "text": "Comment Text",
            "up_vote": 0,
            "down_vote": 0,
            "user_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
            "created_at": "2020-05-29T13:14:07.103072Z",
            "modified_at": "2020-05-29T13:14:07.103124Z",
            "parent_id": null
        }
    ],
    "user_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
    "title": "My Post",
    "description": "Post Description",
    "pictures": "No Pictures",
    "lat": "12",
    "long": "12",
    "vote": "12",
    "created_at": "2020-05-29T13:14:07.102316Z",
    "modified_at": "2020-05-29T13:14:07.102356Z"
}
```

## Lastly

---

I looked at the guide you are referring to and did not see a reference to decouple models with UUID's. While you *can* do that (and in some cases may be necessary) I would think hard on whether you truly need that much decoupling.

There are reasons to use foreign keys over UUID's such as accessing the related models easier and faster. Decoupling using UUID's means you will need to write more boilerplate code every time you need to access a related model.

It comes down to deciding whether you need decoupling or a better developer experience with (subjectively) cleaner code. Please don't just follow a guide and assume it's law. More experience will help with this.

For example, if you used a foreign key relationship your `PostSerializer` could look like the following:

**example_serializers.py**

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

See how we got rid of the `get_comments(self, obj)` method? That was just one bit of boilerplate that we got rid of by making the design decision to use foreign key relationships. Now just imagine a codebase of millions of lines of code and many serializers. Remember, the more code you write the more testing/debugging you need to do as well.

Again, just my opinion, but be sure you actually need to decouple your models before you do it.

Also, I **strongly** recommend you follow the [DRF tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). It reviews everything you need to accomplish what I just posted here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I would take your advice, it's sensible though. The thing is I am coming from .Net background. I used to follow SOLID strongly. I am unable to re-wire my brain into writing my logic into API.py file. Because If any business logic goes into it, I wont be able to reuse it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Is this why Python has become popular, fast code and less structure?

Comment: You can still use SOLID with Django and Python, there's just different ways to accomplish it. C# is a strongly typed static language so it makes sense that there will be some adjustments needed. I went through the same thing coming from Java/Objective-C.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say "less structure" for Python. I would just say it's different. From what I've seen using it and C#/.NET in the past is that Python is created with a "batteries included" mentality. Check out the "Zen of Python" when you get a chance. Those principles are why many people view writing Python code to be a pleasure. It's made to be simplistic, feature rich, readable and maintainable.

Comment: Here is where I got tripped https://phalt.github.io/django-api-domains/

Comment: These guidelines designed by Python experienced devs, didn't really provide how to completely utilize it for all the cases. I liked the architecture, it's looks reasonable, but I was unable to follow it completely. I will now just go with DRF way as you pointed out, refactor the code base as I get better at it. As a newbie in Django, I just got punk'd.

Comment: Haha no worries. Not sure what the goals of the project you're working on is but that guide is for extremely scalable API's. It's easy to get caught up in trying to make something super "scalable" too early since it's the de-facto goal that gets drilled into our heads. The fact is there are multiple levels of scalability so you can pick and choose what you need and refactor as you need more. A great example of this is when Instagram wanted to become more scalable with their Django/Postgres platform. Check out https://instagram-engineering.com/sharding-ids-at-instagram-1cf5a71e5a5c

Comment: Thanks for sharing a useful article. Actually this is the kind of thinking actually slows me down every time. I always want to fly before I can walk. xD

Answer (score 0):

You could create one serializer called OutputSerializer and include the comments as its own field? if you change `comments = OutputCommentSerializer` to `comments = CommentsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` I believe that will depict what you want...(example below).  You already defined CommentSerializer, thus you can use it.

```
class ReportGetApi(APIView):    
     class OutputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'pictures', 'lat', 'long', 'vote', 'comments')

    class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Comments
            fields = ('post_id', 'parent_id', 'text', 'up_vote', 'down_vote', 'user_id', 'created_at', 'modified_at')

    def get(self, request):
        post = PostService.get_post() #Only one item
        comments = PostService.get_comments() #Many Items

        serializer = self.OutputSerializer(post, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I am sorry, I fail to see how this is not similar to my code above?

Comment: changing `comments = OutputCommentsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` to `comments = CommentsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` on the Output Serializer class

Comment: My bad, that's obviously a typo. and Is there a way to do it without foreign key? I need accomplish this without foreign key.

Comment: constructing two models together typically involves adding a ForeignKey to the associated data model.  What is the rationale for not updating the  Comments data model to include a Post ForeignKey relation?

Comment: As per the standard guideline that I attached above states that I should not use foreign key but rather just join them in the service manually. Main reason is they suggest this, is possibly to avoid tight coupling making it look like microservices

Comment: have you tried making the change as I indicated above and does the api render the post with the associated comments?